# Navigation Controller in landscape with Storyboard [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, landscape

I'm working with Navigation Controller in my storyboard, but my application is always in portrait format when I put the simulator in landscape. Why? =(

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

To

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Also make sure in your project settings you have 'Supported Device Orientations' set to allow Landscape.

Comment: Not work! :(  The Xcode enter this code when I only use landscape orientation.

Comment: @GeraldoBastos Do you have landscape enabled in your settings? The above will trigger anytime the device rotates to any position except portrait upside down.